# Why READ_PHONE_STATE permission asked "make and manage phone call"?

Tags: android, permissions

For getting the IMEI i using from this code:

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
       if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, 1);
        } else { 
                iMEI = tm.getDeviceId(); 
        }
```

But when my app is running this dialog box coming up:

[image]

The program asks to grant permission `To make and manage phone calls` which can scary users from using app.

> And now my question is:
>
> **Why READ_PHONE_STATE permission asked "make and manage phone call"?** While  I have not make phone call and manage phone call in my
> app.

Answer (score 9):

`READ_PHONE_STATE` permission is listed as Dangerous permission and provides access to read phone state. It comes under the `Phone` permission group. If dangerous permission is asked, the system shows dialog related to its group. in your case, `Phone`. and That is the reason- the user is asked for "make and manage phone call" permission. This is how the permissions are asked- 
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

To make it more clear, see 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview

It says -

> If the device is running Android 6.0 (API level 23) and the app's
>   targetSdkVersion is 23 or higher, the following system behavior
>   applies when your app requests a dangerous permission:
>
> - If the app doesn't currently have any permissions in the permission    group, the system shows the permission request dialog to the user
>     describing the permission group that the app wants access to. The
>     dialog doesn't describe the specific permission within that group.
>     For example, if an app requests the READ_CONTACTS permission, the
>     system dialog just says the app needs access to the device's
>     contacts. If the user grants approval, the system gives the app just
>     the permission it requested.
> - If the app has already been granted another dangerous permission in    the same permission group, the system immediately grants the
>     permission without any interaction with the user. For example, if an
>     app had previously requested and been granted the READ_CONTACTS
>     permission, and it then requests WRITE_CONTACTS, the system
>     immediately grants that permission without showing the permissions
>     dialog to the user.

There are a lot of better ways to get a unique identifier. For example-

```
String android_id = Settings.Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why READ_PHONE_STATE permission asked "make and manage phone call"?
>   While I have not make phone call and manage phone call in my app.

After Marshmallow we need to explicitly call the permissions which come under **Dangerous permission**.

`READ_PHONE_STATE` comes under **Permission Group** Called [**Phone**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#permission-groups)

Answer (score 0):

Because google got lazy. It is the same with READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE